# Put only existing subcollection in a list firebase(flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to put document snapshots of a sub-collection in a list. The code for it is something like this:-

```
getcoffeebuyerlist() async {
      DocumentSnapshot coffeebuyers;
      List<DocumentSnapshot> finalCoffeBuyerList = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < profiles.length; i++) {
        coffeebuyers = await Firestore.instance
            .collection('profileData')
            .document(profiles[i].uid)
            .collection('coffeeprices')
            .document(profiles[i].uid)
            .get();
        finalCoffeBuyerList.add(coffeebuyers);
      }
      return finalCoffeBuyerList;
    }
```

There are two profile and only one of which has a sub-collection `'coffeeprices'`.

My doubt here is by trying get snapshot of sub-collections, will I automatically be creating an empty document for the second profile for which sub-collection doesn't exist and put in `finalCoffeBuyerList` list?

Or only those(one in my case) sub-collection which already exist are added to this list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code here will never create any documents.  `get()` doesn't create a document if the document doesn't already exist.  You should check the returned [DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html) to see if the document actually [exists](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/exists.html).  Something like this:

```
if (coffeebuyers.exists) {
  finalCoffeBuyerList.add(coffeebuyers);
}
```

The only way to create a document is with `add()` or `set()`.